# How kan Send a file with mail If there is the new file(today's date) in the directory?

Tags: powershell, email

I will have a powershell script to look in a directory, if there is a new file with  today's date (file name: Orbit2Spor_201812140200.csv) then send it via mail to my mail address!
I do not know how can I check a file that has arrived today in a directory, so I have not written foreach and asked the question here?

```
     `# Mail parametrar.
      $PSEmailServer = "smtpmail.test.com"
      $MailFrom = "am.b@Yahoo.com"
      $MailTo = "am.b@Yahoo.com"
      $Subject = "Larm!"
      $MBody = "Test"
      $Attachment = $File

  #################################################################

       $FolderSpor = "C:\temp\CSV"
       $date = (get-date).date
       if (test-path $FolderSpor)
  {
         $files = Get-ChildItem -path $FolderSpor
        foreach ($File in $Files){
       if(((Get-Item $File).CreationTime) -gt $date)

     {
       Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom -Subject $Subject - 
       Body $MBody -Attachments $Attachment
 }
 }
 }`
```

Comment: This post is not a question in it's current form. It's half an order or half a statement, I'm not quite sure. Please edit your original post to include the full code you're trying to run and a detailed explanation of how it doesn't work the way you expected.

Comment: not only do you seem to lack a question, you also seem to lack part of the code. what comes after the `foreach`?

Comment: `$TodaysFiles = gci ("\\server1\C$\folder1\CSV\Orbit2Spor_{0}*.csv" -f [datetime]::Today.ToString('yyyyMMdd'))` then check the .count property. BTW I'd use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) for the mail paramters

Comment: I do not know how can I check a file that has arrived today in a directory, so I have not written foreach and asked the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you simple script that will get all the files in the folder and will check if there is any file created today as you ask. I assume you know what to do with the files you find.

```
## Your folder Path
$folderpath = "C:\temp"
## Getting today date (only date with no time)
$date = (get-date).Date

## Checking if the path is reachable 
if (Test-Path $folderpath)
   {
    ## getting all the files in the folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem $folderpath
    ## Running a for each loop for all the files
    foreach ($file in $files)
          {
           ## checking if the file creation time is today
           if(((Get-Item $file).CreationTime) -gt $date)
             {
               ## do what you want here
             }
          }
    }
```

Hope it will help you, let me know if you need anything else.